# Easiest way to concatenate NSString and int

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Is there a general purpose function in Objective-C that I can plug into my project to simplify concatenating `NSString`s and `int`s?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both answers are correct. If you want to concatenate multiple strings and integers use NSMutableString's appendFormat.

```
NSMutableString* aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"String with one int %d", myInt];    // does not need to be released. Needs to be retained if you need to keep use it after the current function.
[aString appendFormat:@"... now has another int: %d", myInt];
```

Comment: I am using something like that for string concatenation but it gives me a warning: "Local declaration of 'aString' hides instance variable".What could be generating this error?

Comment: Isn't an equal sign missing after aString?

Answer (score 35):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"THIS IS A STRING WITH AN INT: %d", myInt];
```

That's typically how I do it.

Comment: Also look into localizedStringWithFormat: and initWithFormat:locale: when formatting a number for use on screen.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *s = 
   [
       [NSString alloc] 
           initWithFormat:@"Concatenate an int %d with a string %@", 
            12, @"My Concatenated String"
   ];
```

I know you're probably looking for a shorter answer, but this is what I would use.

Comment: Is this the same as [NSString stringWithFormat:] ?

Comment: With this method you will need to release the string when you're done with it.

Comment: @Debajit, it's basically, the same. You'll have to release the string after you use it.

Answer (score 3):

string1,x , these are declared as a string object and integer variable respectively. and if you want to combine both the values and to append int values to a string object and to assign the result to a new string then do as follows.

```
NSString *string1=@"Hello"; 

int x=10;

NSString *string2=[string1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d ",x];

NSLog(@"string2 is %@",string2);


//NSLog(@"string2 is %@",string2); is used to check the string2 value at console ;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the real answer is no - there is no easy and short way to concatenate NSStrings with Objective C - nothing similar to using the '+' operator in C# and Java.